# How do I display a tooltip when focus is in a specific textbox?

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0, tooltip

For a textbox, I want to display a tooltip immediatly when the focus is in on the textbox, and stay there for the duration of the focus - not just when the mouse hovers over the textbox.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Enter` and `Leave` events are probably useful here, and show it with a duration of 0 to keep it there.

```
private ToolTip tt;

private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  tt = new ToolTip();
  tt.InitialDelay = 0;
  tt.IsBalloon = true;
  tt.Show(string.Empty, textBox1);
  tt.Show("I need help", textBox1, 0);
}

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  tt.Dispose();
}
```

Note: Calling the `Show(...)` method twice like in my example will force the "pointer" to point correctly to the control.

Comment: I would recommend checking if tt is null in the Leave event. There maybe instances where the Enter event is not triggered and then you'll get a null reference error on the Leave event.

Answer (score 6):

have tested, the event names:

```
   private void textbox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.Show("your tip here", textbox);

    }

    private void textbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.Hide(textbox);

    }
```

tooltip is a control, needs to be added from toolbox.

Answer (score 4):

using `mouse hover` and `mouse leave` events

```
    private void textBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.Show("your tip here", textBox2);

    }

    private void textBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.Hide(textBox2);
    }
```

>

Answer (score 1):

> Windows Forms

```
public partial class FormWindow : Form
{
        //Constructor
        public FormWindow()
        {
            txtUrl.Text = "Enter text here";
            txtUrl.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            txtUrl.GotFocus += TxtUrl_GotFocus;
            txtUrl.LostFocus += TxtUrl_LostFocus;
        }

        private void TxtUrl_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtUrl.Text = "";
            txtUrl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }

        private void TxtUrl_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUrl.Text))
            {
                txtUrl.Text = "Enter text here";
                txtUrl.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip and show it in textbox **GotFocus** event and Hide it in **LostFocus** event:

```
void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip.Show("your tip", textBox);
}

void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip.Hide(textBox);
}
```

Comment: Any ideas why these events don't appear in the Visual Studio Properties pane when `Enter` and `Leave` do?

Comment: public Constructor()
        {
            txtUrl.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            txtUrl.GotFocus += TxtUrl_GotFocus;
            txtUrl.LostFocus += TxtUrl_LostFocus;
        }

        private void TxtUrl_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtUrl.Text = "";
            txtUrl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }

        private void TxtUrl_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUrl.Text))
                txtUrl.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        }